# Weird timing issue with Mathjax

Tags: mathjax, pagedown

I'm using MathJax with PageDown in a pretty straight forward way.

```
InitMathjax(converter); 
var html = converter.makeHtml(text);
var $pageText = ...;
$pageText.html(html);
```

This works most of the time when I run the site locally, and almost never works when I run it in production. The result can also vary between each reload, so I think there is some kind of race condition based on how long it takes for various scripts to load and run.
I've tried doing `Mathjax.Hub.Reprocess()` and such, which don't seem to help. Doing `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, $pageText.get(0)]);` 100ms after the above code seems to have fixed the issue. But this feels like a patch, and the font looks off in production. (Looks like mathjax generated html ends up in a `<span class="MathJax_Preview">`, rather than `<span class="MathJax">`).
I want to understand the issue so I can actually fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a live sample? Random guess would be that math nodes get deleted during typesetting.

Comment: Thanks for asking. Here is a page that I got to work with the Queue "Typeset" trick: http://zanaduu3.appspot.com/pages/Markdown-1  
Here is a page that kind of works, but the font is off: http://zanaduu3.appspot.com/pages/5224512630340297553

Comment: Also if you look at the answer on the second page, you'll see that it has the problem of not being process by mathjax completely. Color font becomes gray.  
Also worth pointing out that on that page, if you start typing an answer, the preview works perfectly fine with mathjax.

Comment: It's also very strange because the second link loads correctly, but then if you refresh it, the mathjax breaks.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem anymore, I'm afraid.

Comment: So if you go to this [link](http://zanaduu3.appspot.com/pages/5224512630340297553) and refresh it a bunch of times, none of those times generate a page with broken mathjax?